# Raspbian OS using Arm Assembly and I get a segmentation Fault

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I am brand new to Assembly, my goal was to make a simple a program that takes two numbers from the user then adds them and displays the sum. Now what I cant figure out is why I get the segmentation error, I have a feeling the line MOV R2,SP is the culprit but I'm not sure. So if anyone could tell me what the problem is and show me how to solve it I would greatly appreciate it.
P.S-Could you explain what exactly a segmentation fault is?
CODE

```
----------------------------------------------------------



  .global main
    .func main
    .extern scanf
    main:
        BL _prompt
        BL _scanf
        BL _scanf2
        ADD R1,R1,R2
        BL _printf
        BL _exit

    _exit:
      MOV R7,#4
      MOV R0,#1
      MOV R2,#21
      LDR R1, =exit_str
      SWI 0
      MOV R7,#1
      SWI 0

     _prompt:
       MOV R7,#4
       MOV R0,#1
       MOV R2,#31
       LDR R1,=prompt_str
       SWI 0
       MOV PC, LR

    _printf:
       MOV R4, LR
       LDR R0, =printf_str
       MOV R1,R1
       BL printf
       MOV PC, R4

    _scanf:
      PUSH {LR}
      SUB SP, SP, #4
      LDR R0, =format_str
      MOV R1,SP
      BL scanf
      LDR R1,[SP]
      ADD SP,SP,#4
      POP {PC}

     _scanf2:
      PUSH {LR}
      SUB SP, SP, #4
      LDR R0, =format_str2
      MOV R2,SP
      BL scanf
      LDR R2,[SP]
      ADD SP,SP,#4
      POP {PC}

    .data
format_str:  .asciz   "%d"
format_str2:  .asciz   "%d"
prompt_str:   .asciz    "Type a number and press enter: "
printf_str:    .asciz   "The number entered was: %d\n"
exit_str:       .ascii   "Terminating program.\n"
```

Comment: You should run the program under a debugger, but the `MOV R2,SP` line is definitely wrong as the second argument needs to be passed in R1, just like when you called `scanf` previously. Also note that `scanf` won't preserve R0, R1, R2 or R3 so can't save the result of the previous call in to `scanf` in R1.

Comment: Could you give tips on code?, and also I dont know how to run debugger as I am using a raspian OS emulator

Comment: I could be mistaken, but i think the strings must be aligned with ".align 4"

Comment: What is the reason for mixing syscalls and C functions; i.e., printf, scanf. Is that a requirement for the assignment?

Answer (score 0):

This hasty code example uses C functions printf, scanf, and exit. The code works but is not necessarily confirming to coding standards.

Whenever I have multiple printf and scanf items, I like using a single _print and _scan function then insert the parameters before the call to the function.

hardware - OS:

```
  $ uname -a
    Linux raspberrypi 4.4.50-v7+ #970 SMP Mon Feb 20 19:18:29 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

    $ lshw
    ...
        description: Computer
        product: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B Rev 1.1

    $ cat /etc/os-release
    PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
    ...
```

code:

```
.data
        format_str:     .asciz   "%d"
       // format_str2:    .asciz   "%d" - not required
        prompt_str:     .asciz   "Type a number and press enter: \n"
        printf_str:     .asciz   "The number entered was: %d\n"
        exit_str:       .asciz   "Terminating program.\n"
        total_str:      .asciz  "The total is %d!\n"
.text
.global main
        .func main
        .extern printf, scanf, exit
main:

        ldr r0,=prompt_str
        bl _print

        ldr r0,=format_str
        bl _scan
        mov r10, r0             // save value

        ldr r0,=printf_str
        mov r1, r10
        bl _print

        ldr r0,=prompt_str
        bl _print

        ldr r0,=format_str
        bl _scan
        mov r11, r0             // save value

        ldr r0,=printf_str
        mov r1, r11
        bl _print

        ldr r0,=total_str
        add r1, r10, r11
        bl _print

        ldr r0,=exit_str
        bl _print

_exit:
        bl exit

_print:
        push {lr}
        bl printf
        pop {pc}

_scan:
        push {lr}
        sub sp,sp ,#4
        mov r1, sp              // place data to stack
        bl scanf
        ldr r0, [sp]            // return data
        add sp, sp, #4
        pop {pc}
```

output sample:

```
./xavier_001
Type a number and press enter:
1234
The number entered was: 1234
Type a number and press enter:
1111
The number entered was: 1111
The total is 2345!
Terminating program.
```